# Colours to use in a fashion website

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, visual-design

I am working on a fashion website for my own portfolio. However it allows users to have their own account where they can save fashion related items. A sort of Pinterest for fashion items.

Now, I know that the most widely used colours are black and white or white and black for online fashion stores. With so much choice, I wondered if it is ok to add tints of other colours or will this destroy the UX? If yes, which tints do you think I should add and are best suited? I was thinking of a sleek, modern and retro(ish) design, that is largely flat.

Share your vision with me. How would you do it?

Comment: I don't see the UX question here.  It seems to be more of a design question.

Comment: @JohnGB - yes, but visual design questions can be answered in much the same way as UX questions - by considering a use case, a viewer and what the organisation hopes to communicate.

Comment: @JohnGB I would say that a good 30-40% (if not more) of your UX depends on your UI and the design approach you take. Patterns, colours, palettes all matter in UX.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye the problem is that those sorts of questions are subjective and so amount to a discussion. There are good examples that use almost every colour, and people supporting every one.

Comment: @Elmar  It is possible to do UX without ever touching on visual design, especially if they are looking at UX as an end to end thing. If someone is doing visual design as well as UX then it's likely they're working on smaller projects with a small team. For medium to large projects it's better to get in specialists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick to black and white. There are a few reasons for this.

Firstly, using a standard aesthetic for the domain will **help users recognise the purpose of your site**. This, in turn, reduces the amount of 'work' your design must do to explain the content of your pages.

Secondly, luxury products benefit from being displayed in a minimalistic manner thanks to the **horror vacuii** effect. You'll find black and white an easier scheme to work with for minimalism, because you don't need accent colours different from your type (text) colours. I would probably not use pure black and white (I'd reduce the contrast to look a little less cheaply utilitarian), but a dual colour scheme is probably the right choice.

Finally, I would worry that other key colours might take attention away from the products. Your product photos need to be the most striking thing on screen, without exception. Browns and maybe dark blues are acceptable, but anything in the red or yellow ranges is going to take too much focus.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. Also I got another question. I am organising the images in sort of Pinterest mode, but without any background (sort of like niice.co). On hover, an additional options menu appears. Although it looks beautiful, it has many setbacks in UX. Do you think this is the best approach for a user centered website?

Comment: @Elmar - that's impossible to say without knowing what content you're revealing on hover, what the use case is and what clues you've provided that the content exists. I fear you may be thinking the question is much simpler than it actually is.

Comment: @Elmar - if you found the response helpful, could you please upvote it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Jimmy, even though I found it great advice, my reputation is still not high enough to give out votes. I tried to vote up, but I need a reputation of 15. But as soon as I get it, I will vote up.

Comment: Having worked on several fashion sites the issue with black and white is that there is a strong chance that sites become samey. From a usability point of view this can lead to a lack of context for the user. The aim is to be legible and clear - past that it is down to the complexities that a good visual designer will understand and is a case for UX people to work with design specialists.

Comment: @StewartDean - you are, of course, assuming that it's more valuable to communicate the identity of the site than immediately express its purpose. Depending on your objectives, though, that assumption might be incorrect.

Comment: @StewartDean - could there be ways to achieve the three "benefits" of black and white schemes I mentioned without having to stick to monochrome, though?

Comment: @ Jimmy Breck-McKye For a fashion site identity is a key component and the purpose is communicated by the content. If the site is working well then the user sees the colours of the products and editorial before the colours of the 'site'. It's those elements that should tell a user, quickly, what the site is and what it does. I agree on your points that minimal design allows the products to live but there are many ways to do that beyond simple black and white. As a UX designer I personally don't get involved with that - that's the visual designers job.